# how to view a url as a sting using htmlString

Tags: html, meteor

I want to view all the items in my database and i managed to retrieve all except for the image.

This is my code:

```
 htmlString += '<div class="col-md-4"> ImageShouldGoHere </div>';
 htmlString += '<div class="col-md-8">';
 htmlString += '<div class="col-md-12 listing-title"> ' + data[i].title + ' </div>';
 htmlString += '<div class="col-md-12 category-text"> ' + data[i].category + ' </div>';
```

The URL of the image is located in `data[i].previewImage` how can i view the URL as an image in the place of `ImageShouldGoHere`?

Comment: `htmlString += '<div class="col-md-4"><img src="' + data[i].previewImage + '" /></div>';`

Comment: @HanletEscaño Thanks, it worked

Answer (score 0):

putting the image url as a src of  `img` tag would do the job.

```
htmlString += '<div class="col-md-4"><img src="' + data[i].previewImage + '" /></div>';
```

Comment: sorry, i did not see the comment earlier. it's been solved by @Hanlet